# Wordpress: htaccess point folder to root directory?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

1. I have a domain: `www.domain.com` - not wordpress cms, install folder *public_html* in hosting.
2. I have a website English and German version - use wordpress cms.
3. I install wordpress cms in folder: *public_html/en/*
4. Link follow:
   `www.domain.com` not wordpress cms.
   `www.domain.com/en/` wordpress cms root (English default)
   `www.domain.com/en/de` wordpress German version.

**=>** How to run the German version with the link as follow: `www.domain.com/de`

I tried with the `.htaccess` in the public_html folder but not run:

```
 RewriteRule ^/de$ /en/index.php
```

Thank all!

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect solution because WP is in charge of the URLs.

So even if the following is working, the URLs that WP put on your Website are still `/en/de` and so the user will always be clicking on `/en/de` and get than redirected to `/de`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?en/de(/.*)?$ /de$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?de(/.*)?$ /en/de$1 [L]
```

#### Update:

If this is not working than you still have the WP issue, because WP can't interpreter the URL right, therefor this could not be solved by htaccess itself.

Comment: Run /de is english version.

Comment: Thank you! It working, but:
- Link /de: version english.
- Link /de/...: page, archive not right.

Comment: We can exclude /en/de but archive is a WP issue

Answer (score 0):

Put the folowing code at your main root `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+de/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/de/(.*)$ de/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ en/de/$1 [L]
```

The code above will only remove `en` if request contains `en/de` externally and redirect it internally to same path .

Test it , if it is ok , change `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection .

**Note:** clear your browser cache and test it .

Comment: did you place .htaccess in public_htm folder? or where?

Comment: .htaccess in public_html

Comment: it should work , try to save your htaccess and test it alone